# Rocket.Chat REST API "/api/v1/users.register" Not Reponding

Tags: rocket.chat

#### Description:

Requesting to endpoint: "/api/v1/users.register" is not responding on my self-hosted Rocket.Chat server running on docker.
The rest of the APIs seem to be fine and only this one is not sending back 200 OK HTTPS response and I face the request timed out.

Although the requested JSON data has been sent to the server and the requested user has been registered cause if I try to send the same request again I get the 400 Bad Request with the error: "Username is already in use".

#### Steps to reproduce:

curl -H "Content-type:application/json" 
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users.register 
-d '{ "username": "rogersmith", "email": "roger@example.com", "pass": "passw0rd", "name": "Roger Smith"}'

#### Expected behavior:

HTTP status code: 200 Ok
JSON result:
{
"user": {
"_id": "nSYqWzZ4GsKTX4dyK",
"type": "user",
"status": "offline",
"active": true,
"name": "Example User",
"utcOffset": 0,
"username": "example"
},
"success": true
}

#### Actual behavior:

Literally nothing!

#### Server Setup Information:

- Version of Rocket.Chat Server: 3.11.0
- Operating System: Ubuntu Linux 18.04.2
- Deployment Method: docker-compose
- MongoDB Version: 4.0.0